# The commercial at key has swapped with the double inverted commas key

Tags: windows, keyboard, remapping

Ever since I loaded Windows 10 the double inverted commas key (") on my wired keyboard has swapped with the commercial at key (@).

Can anybody please tell me how to swap them back?

Comment: Just to note that @ above 2 and " above ' is Apple default layout, reversed is Windows default.

Comment: You picked the wrong keyboard layout during Windows setup.

Answer (score 1):

Likely your keyboard layout has been changed to a layout with that key arrangement.

If you have multiple keyboard layouts enabled, check that you are using your intended layout.

You can check your enabled/selected keyboard layouts under `Settings > Time & Language > Region & Language`, or using the keyboard layout switcher in the Task Bar.

The following images illustrate the process using the Windows 10 Settings App for the US Keyboard.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with a Apple Mac Keyboard connected.

It happens after a while. Windows 10 just @forgets@ sorry, that should read "forgets" (it is happening again at the moment) the keyboard settings.

Windows 10 is not exactly a "finished" product.

All I have to do is restart my computer and all is fine again.
It is annoying and it only happens after my machine has been left on for a couple of weeks, but restarting it fixes it every time for me.

I hope this works for you. I'm sure Microsoft will catch up with all of the bugs in Win10 sooner or later. They got there, mostly, with XP.

Comment: Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: Apologies, I was trying to explain what fixed the problem for me (and continues to fix the problem for me when it happens) in the hope it would fix the problem for the question asker. I will try to be more careful. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I rectified the matter by deleting the UK keyboard & rebooted. The system found the US keyboard & all is well.